# Google maps doesn't show up. Just a blank space

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I am fairly new to HTML and CSS, I am following a study that does include this. Now I want to include google maps into my site, but it isn't working... There is just a big blank space on my screen. I have done it before, and I have repeated everything several times. I just can't get it to work.

I got a Javascript from school, and followed the steps I know. Maybe someone can look into it? 
Thanks in advance.

P.S. If I made any other mistakes, please correct me ;)

**My Javascript (saved as maps.js in the same folder as the rest)**

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var map;
var markers = [
    ['Kapelstraat 13',27.175015,78.042155],
];

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        draggable: true,
        panControl: false,
        scrollwheel: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.175015,78.042155)
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    setMarkers();
}

function setMarkers(){
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var post = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: post,
            map: map
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: markers[i][0]
        });

        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
}
```

**My page where I want to include maps.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>LOFT13</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="zaak.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDHAB5YtEF9hCPSG3BduJAsY6RyIMeqOr8&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="maps.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>

    <div id= "map-canvas">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**My CSS about maps**

```
/* maps */

.map {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#map-canvas {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please visit the [help] and also read [ask] for tips on writing good questions. As it stands, your question is not on-topic as you have not described the problem beyond _"It doesn't work"_.

Comment: [The posted code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kmjqso62/1/)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I'm also new on this site haha. The google maps isn't showing up. it's just a blank space on my site. I don't get any error or something else.

Comment: I see @geocodezip unfortunately it didn't for me, but JTerry already helped fix me the problem! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `initailize()` to `initMap()` to match up with the callback in the api call: `callback=initMap`. Also, make sure to consulted the documentation [from google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en). It's pretty well laid out in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast! You were right and it is showing up now! I know, it was all clear for me, but english isn't my first language to begin with, so I got a little confused...